# Use global variable value in AJAX JSON POST request

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to make a AJAX call to post some JSON to my Elasticsearch instance. Is there anyway I can use a global variables value in the 'data' request?

Something like the below?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Log-submit').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var btn = $(e.target);
        btn.attr("disabled", "disabled"); // disable button
    $.ajax({
      data: JSON.stringify({"name" : "#div.Name"}),  //use global variable value in JSON POST request
      dataType: 'json',
      processData: false,
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      url: 'http://my-API.com:9200/escalations/'
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: You certainly can use a global variable in the AJAX request - except your code isn't doing that. You're just sending the '#div.Name' string literal. Are you trying to send the text or some attribute of that element instead? Also, if this is a cross-domain request, ensure that the other domain returns CORS headers.

Comment: $('#div.Name').val() - Would this work?

Comment: I have a value taken from "#div.Name" say its 'John Smith' I want to send the POST request as the following to update my ES index.

"name" : "John Smith"

Comment: you can use global `window` object to set global variable.

Answer (score 1):

From your description in the comments it sounds as though you want to select the element `#div.Name` and then send the value (assuming it's an `<input />` element) in the AJAX request. Note that this is different logic from a global variable, but still easily possible.

To what you require, you need to select the element then get it's `val()`, like this:

```
$.ajax({
  data: { name: $('#div.Name').val() },
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'POST',
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  url: 'http://my-API.com:9200/escalations/'
});
```

Also note that I removed `processData` as setting it to `false` was meaning that you needed to encode the JSON manually, which is redundant when jQuery will do it for you, given the correct `contentType`.